# Prove "If x and y are irrational numbers, then 3x+4xy+2y is irrational"

Tags: proof-writing, rational-numbers

How would I go proving this? I tried contrapositive and contradiction approaches but both don't look very correct for proof. For contrapositive I must always assume x to be irrational to reach conclusion but this seems incorrect approach. I appreciate any help you may give.
I assume negation of original implication, then I solved for y. This is when I say x = $\sqrt{2}$ an irrational number. The rest is logical, but this assumption of x seems incorrect for proof.

Comment: This is false.  Say $x=\pi$ and $y=-\frac 12\times \pi$.  Then $3x+4xy+2y=(3-2-1)\pi=0$.

Comment: It is considered poor form to clear your own question after you receive an answer. If you're satisfied, leave it up and accept the answer.

Comment: Please don't remove or deface your question after an answer has been posted (and upvoted).

Comment: Close this question because the title was edited several times after answers were given

Comment: \pi example is wrong

Comment: x = pi, y = -pi/2, 3x+4xy+2y = 3pi + 4pi(-pi/2)+2(-pi/2) = 3pi - 2pi^2 - pi = (3 - 2pi - 1)pi != 0. thus, pi example incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

It's false. Let $x=\sqrt{2}/3$ and $y=-\sqrt{2}/2$. Both are irrational but $3x+4xy+2y=-4/3$ is rational.